# ansible: adding some project specific path to virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, ansible

I need to add `project` and `lib` directory to my virtualenv in the ansible playbook.
I'm installing dependencies like this:

```
- pip: 
    name: virtualenv

- pip:
    requirements: "{{project_dir}}requirements/development.txt"
    virtualenv: "{{ virtualenv_path }}"
    state: latest
```

On the development machine I can do this with:

```
$ add2virtualenv project
$ add2virtualenv lib
```

but I don't wan't to install `virtualenvwrapper` on the server.
So, what is the idiomatic way to setup virtualenv with ansible properly in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following shell script instead of [add2virtualenv](https://bitbucket.org/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper/src/3ca89a29ab6c12fa6974f4f31d1520aaed921808/virtualenvwrapper.sh?fileviewer=file-view-default#virtualenvwrapper.sh-815) that [doing this](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#add2virtualenv):

> Adds the specified directories to the Python path for the
>   currently-active virtualenv.
>
> Syntax:
>
> add2virtualenv directory1 directory2 ...
>
> Sometimes it is desirable to share installed packages that are not in
>   the system site-packages directory and which should not be installed
>   in each virtualenv. One possible solution is to symlink the source
>   into the environment site-packages directory, but it is also easy to
>   add extra directories to the PYTHONPATH by including them in a .pth
>   file inside site-packages using add2virtualenv.
>
> ```
> Check out the source for a big project, such as Django.
> Run: add2virtualenv path_to_source.
> Run: add2virtualenv.
> A usage message and list of current “extra” paths is printed.
> ```
>
> The directory names are added to a path file named
>   _virtualenv_path_extensions.pth inside the site-packages directory for the environment.

Shell script:

```
# Path management for packages outside of the virtual env.
# Based on a contribution from James Bennett and Jannis Leidel.
#
# add2virtualenv directory1 directory2 ...
#
# Adds the specified directories to the Python path for the
# currently-active virtualenv. This will be done by placing the
# directory names in a path file named
# "virtualenv_path_extensions.pth" inside the virtualenv's
# site-packages directory; if this file does not exist, it will be
# created first.
#
#:help:add2virtualenv: add directory to the import path
function add2virtualenv {
    virtualenvwrapper_verify_workon_home || return 1
    virtualenvwrapper_verify_active_environment || return 1

    site_packages="`virtualenvwrapper_get_site_packages_dir`"

    if [ ! -d "${site_packages}" ]
    then
        echo "ERROR: currently-active virtualenv does not appear to have a site-packages directory" >&2
        return 1
    fi

    # Prefix with _ to ensure we are loaded as early as possible,
    # and at least before easy_install.pth.
    path_file="$site_packages/_virtualenv_path_extensions.pth"

    if [ "$*" = "" ]
    then
        echo "Usage: add2virtualenv dir [dir ...]"
        if [ -f "$path_file" ]
        then
            echo
            echo "Existing paths:"
            cat "$path_file" | grep -v "^import"
        fi
        return 1
    fi

    remove=0
    if [ "$1" = "-d" ]
    then
        remove=1
        shift
    fi

    if [ ! -f "$path_file" ]
    then
        echo "import sys; sys.__plen = len(sys.path)" > "$path_file" || return 1
        echo "import sys; new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:]; p=getattr(sys,'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert = p+len(new)" >> "$path_file" || return 1
    fi

    for pydir in "$@"
    do
        absolute_path="$(virtualenvwrapper_absolutepath "$pydir")"
        if [ "$absolute_path" != "$pydir" ]
        then
            echo "Warning: Converting \"$pydir\" to \"$absolute_path\"" 1>&2
        fi

        if [ $remove -eq 1 ]
        then
            sed -i.tmp "\:^$absolute_path$: d" "$path_file"
        else
            sed -i.tmp '1 a\
'"$absolute_path"'
' "$path_file"
        fi
        rm -f "${path_file}.tmp"
    done
    return 0
}
```